# Set the time of the DatePicker

Tags: xcode, datepicker, nsdate, nscalendar

How do I set the time of the DatePicker at 00:00:00 of the current date?

```
   - (void) awakeFromNib
    {
        [datePicker setDateValue:[NSDate date]];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        int daysToAdd = 364;
        NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
        [datePicker1 setDateValue:newDate1];
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358678/how-do-i-set-an-existing-nsdates-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*cringe*

It looks like you have two different datePickers?  `datePicker` and `datePicker1`?  What's up with that?

Also, this does not do what you're expecting:

```
NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*364];
```

That is creating a new date that is exactly 31,449,600 seconds in the future.  It is *not* doing anything other than that.

What you want to do is extract all of the date *components* from the current date and zero them out:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];

// technically these next lines are unnecessary, since we only pulled out the era-year-month-day, but they're included here for understanding/completeness:

[nowComponents setHour:0];
[nowComponents setMinute:0];
[nowComponents setSecond:0];

// now we can turn it back into a date:

NSDate *todayAtMidnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
```