# Convert static time to NSDate returns older date

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsdateformatter

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[df setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
NSLog(@" >> %@ >>> %@",date,[df dateFromString:@"12:18 AM"])
```

And log is

```
>> 2014-04-10 07:00:48 +0000 >>> 2000-01-01 06:52:00 +0000
```

I want that the second date has also the same date as the first.

like

```
  2014-04-10 07:00:48 +0000 >>> 2014-04-10 06:52:00 +0000
```

Comment: If you don't put month/day/year, that will be hard... Try with `NSDateComponents` instead.

Comment: See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358678/how-do-i-set-an-existing-nsdates-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the time string "12:18 AM" to a date for the *current day* then you can proceed as follows:

```
NSString *time = @"12:18 AM";

NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

// Get year-month-day for today:
[fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd "];
NSString *todayString = [fmt stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

// Append the given time:
NSString *todaysTime = [todayString stringByAppendingString:time];

// Convert date+time string back to NSDate:
[fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:todaysTime];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

By using this formatter, you can get `NSDate`